# Result with empty values is being added to my query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Invoice and Order model with the following relationship:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to invoice
end
```

In my Invoice model, I am trying to loop through the orders belonging to an invoice using collect. An extra order with nil attributes is being added to my results.

```
 orders.collect{|order| order}
```

Results:

```
[#<Order id: 1, menu_item_id: 1, invoice_id: 1, quantity: 1, status: "Submitted", created_at: "2020-05-25 15:48:25", updated_at: "2020-05-25 15:48:25">,
#<Order id: nil, menu_item_id: nil, invoice_id: 1, quantity: nil, status: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

I have checked the existence of this blank item in the database but I am not seeing anything.

**Edit:**
Fixed this by removing an unnecessary `instance.order.build` in my controller. Thanks to @[3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r) for bringing this up

Comment: Are you adding an order to the collection somewhere? For example `invoice.orders.build` in the controller.

Comment: check part of your create inside invoice

Comment: @3limin4t0r My show method in the controller is adding an order. Removed it as it is unnecessary and this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Things don't magically appear. If there is an empty record in your `orders` collection, you've probably added it somewhere to the collection.

Things like:

```
invoice.orders.build
invoice.orders.new
invoice.orders << Order.new
```

All add an empty order to the orders collection. These actions are commonly found inside the controller `new` and `create` actions, but can also appear in other places.

Once a collection like `invoice.orders` is loaded it will stay loaded for the duration of the request (as long as `invoices` is in scope and you're working on the same `invoice` instance).

The best thing to do is look where you've added this additional instance to the collection and remove the statement if possible. Alternatively you can reload the collection from the database with `invoice.orders.reload` resetting the `orders` collection.